# getStream.io (Chat) - In which database are all the messages stored?

Tags: socket.io, getstream-io

I would be happy to know in **which database are all the messages stored in getStream.io** ?

Answer (score 0):

In a distributed system of Redis, Postgres(CockroachDB), DynamoDB, ElasticSearch and RocksDB.